# Creating API as proxy to DynamoDB

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, gateway

I am following this tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHcslTrkMz4) to create a webservice using dynamoDB and API gateway as a proxy. I managed to get until the final step where after I have created my get method, i ran a test to test my service. However, i got this error :

{
“__type”: “com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException”,
“message”: “ExpressionAttributeValues contains invalid value: One or more parameter values were invalid: An AttributeValue may not contain an empty string for key :v1”
}

Cant seem to find out what the issue is and wanted to ask if anyone encountered this error

Comment: I have solved this issue. Pay attention to the parameter you set and keep the mapping table parameter exactly same as the param you set. My issue came from upper case and lower case difference.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue. Pay attention to the parameter you set and keep the mapping table parameter exactly same as the param you set. My issue came from upper case and lower case difference.